# How do I transpose results of Pandas.Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have created a grouped data frame `total_hours` by employee `id` and total hours they worked each `week`

```
id  week     duration
4       35       7.000000
        36       2.000000
        ...      ...
        40       5.000000
```

How do you transpose the results to the following format?

```
id      35  36  37  38  39  40
4       7.0 2.0 7.0 2.0 4.0 5.0
```

I have tried `total_hours.T` but that is not a valid for `SeriesGroupBy`.

Comment: Since the content of a pandas dataframe can be returned as numpy array, you can just use np.transpose for this task.

Comment: What is the purpose of the transpose? You can simply `reset_index()` to get back to a normal frame/series from your groupby object. Can you please add your code to the question, also?

Comment: Right on @alkasm – that would be my suggestion too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) if `df` is `DataFrame with MultiIndex`:

```
#e.g. possible created df
df = df.groupby(['id', 'week']).sum()

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([(4, 35),
            (4, 36),
            (4, 40)],
           names=['id', 'week'])


df1 = df['duration'].unstack()
print (df1)
week   35   36   40
id                 
4     7.0  2.0  5.0
```

If need `id` to column:

```
df1 = df['duration'].unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
   id   35   36   40
0   4  7.0  2.0  5.0
```

Alternative is if need aggregation `sum`:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='week', values='duration', aggfunc='sum')

df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

try using this:

```
df  = df.pivot(index='id', columns='week', values='duration')
```